# Excel VBA copy value to new

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm brand new to VBA and macros. I've been stumbling along rather decently, but I've come across this problem and I'm not sure how to tweak the code.

I need the user to be able to enter a value (number) to search the entire worksheet for, then once it's found, copy and paste to the next empty cell in column B on another sheet in the same worksheet.

It keeps getting less and less where I want it to be.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Reference_Lookup_Paste()
' Written by Barrie Davidson
Dim datatoFind
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim currentSheet As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
datatoFind = InputBox("Please enter the Reference Number.")
If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Sub
sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count
If IsError(CDbl(datatoFind)) = False Then datatoFind = CDbl(datatoFind)
For counter = 1 To sheetCount
Sheets(counter).Activate
Cells.Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
False).Activate
If ActiveCell.Value = datatoFind Then Call Reference_Move
On Error Resume Next

Next counter
If ActiveCell.Value <> datatoFind Then
MsgBox ("Value not found")
Sheets(currentSheet).Activate
End If
End Sub

Sub Reference_Move()
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Service-Warranty").Select

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Intersect(Range("B:B"), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))
Set r2 = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
If r1 Is Nothing Then
    r2.Select
Else
    r1(1).Select
End If
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Here's the Call If ActiveCell.Value = datatoFind

```
Sub Reference_Move()
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Service-Warranty").Select

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Intersect(Range("B:B"), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))
Set r2 = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
If r1 Is Nothing Then
    r2.Select
Else
    r1(1).Select
End If
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Update: now it will find the value and paste in the proper column, but it pastes 4 cells down instead of just one, and when the data isn't found it still pastes whatever's in the clipboard.

```
Sub Reference_Lookup_Paste()
' Written by Barrie Davidson
Dim datatoFind
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim currentSheet As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
datatoFind = InputBox("Please enter the Reference Number.")
If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Sub
sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count
If IsError(CDbl(datatoFind)) = False Then datatoFind = CDbl(datatoFind)
For counter = 1 To sheetCount
Sheets(counter).Activate
Cells.Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
False).Activate
If ActiveCell.Value = datatoFind Then Selection.Copy

Sheets("Service-Warranty").Select

Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next counter
If ActiveCell.Value <> datatoFind Then
MsgBox ("Value not found")
Sheets(currentSheet).Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the *edit* link just below your question to add information. NOT the comment field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to get away from using `.Select` as a method of referencing cells, cell ranges and even worksheets. Each can be directly referenced in its own way. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) from that other site.

Here is some code that uses direct referencing while accomplishing the goals you've set out.

```
Sub Reference_Lookup_Paste()
    Dim sMsg As String, datatoFind As Variant
    Dim s As Long, rw As Long, cl As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    datatoFind = InputBox("Please enter the Reference Number.")
    If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(datatoFind) Then datatoFind = CDbl(datatoFind)
    sMsg = datatoFind & " found on:" & Chr(10)
    For s = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If Not Sheets(s).Name = "Service-Warranty" Then 'assumed that you want to skip this one
            With Sheets(s).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells, datatoFind)) Then
                    sMsg = sMsg & .Parent.Name & Chr(10)
                    Sheets("Service-Warranty").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = datatoFind
                    Exit For
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next s

    If Len(sMsg) > (InStr(1, sMsg, datatoFind & " found on:" & Chr(10), vbTextCompare) + 1) Then
        MsgBox sMsg
    Else
        MsgBox datatoFind & "Value not found."
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've used VBA's `Application.Countif` to look at all of the populated cells in each worksheet's `.CurrentRegion` at once. The worksheet's `.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion` is the unbroken island of data starting at A1 and continuing both right and down until it encounters a completely blank row or column. You can demonstrate this by selecting A1 and tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: This looks great! The only thing, when it finds the specified value, I need to copy and paste it into the next blank cell in a column on "Service-Warranty"

Comment: It is intended to do just that directly below the `sMsg = sMsg & .Parent.Name & Chr(10)` line. Are you saying that it is not?

Comment: gives a system message indicating where the value is located.
I'm sorry, I'm not well versed at ALL in VBA

Comment: What is the actual (*exact*) error message and have you checked the spelling of the worksheet's name?

Comment: not error message, just a message telling me which cell the searched for value is located. 
This is what I'm aiming for: User inputs a value to search for on sheet "1." If it's found, it copies the cell containing the value and pastes into the next blank cell in column B in sheet "2"